# Finger Painting from a UIView Class to Another UIView Class

Tags: ios, uitouch

I have a UIViewController Class which holds 2 custom UIView classes which are:

ItemView

DrawingView

in UIViewController ViewDidLoad method I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    item = [[ItemView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 230, 230)];
    item.opaque = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:item];

    drawing = [[DrawingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view insertSubview:drawing aboveSubview:item];
    [item release];
    [drawing release];

}
```

The DrawingView class gets UITouches and accordingly draw on the screen.

My question is:

I can draw all over the screen except for on top of ItemView class object. DrawingView class cannot draw on to ItemView.

Let me explain it in another word:

The DrawView class works on the screen except for the area of itemView subview. On top of itemView, DrawView cannot make any draws but other than itemView area, it makes drawing.

What can I do? 
What can be the problem?
How can I make drawing on all screen including the itemView area added by addSubview on ViewController class?

EDIT: I am adding a screenshot in order to explain the problem better

**[image: in this image link you can see that, I can draw on the white area but I cannot draw on the face which is an image loaded by ItemView class.]**

EDIT 2: I found that the problem is related to opacity. In the ItemView class, I changed the  added UIImageView object alpha value to 0.5f. 
The result is semi-transparent view and now my finger drawing is visible. However, this is not what I want. I want to draw on top of the view. I do not want to play with the alpha value.

Comment: `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.view];`
This seems just un-usefull...

Comment: I have been just trying different variations, in order to find a solution but with or without that line, it is not working

Comment: I don't understand; are you trying to make the DrawingView respond to touches above the ItemView because it isn't (from what can be seen here, there's no reason that the DrawingView wouldn't be responding, so it may be problems in another part of your code) or is the DrawingView responding correctly and you are just trying to make it incapable of drawing on top of the ItemView? Or is there some completely other goal that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Carter Pape - DrawingView is a class which arranges drawing on screen based on Finger touches. It works well however, it cannot draw on top of the itemView area. The itemView object is located in the middle of the screen and DrawingView works on all screen except for on top of itemView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer myself. It is not exactly what I wanted but my solution is based on CALayer.

Instead of using a custom UIView class like ItemView I added the following class method in ItemView Class:

```
+(CALayer *)imgLayer
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"];
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(img.CGImage);
    CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(img.CGImage);
    CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
    layer.contents = (id)img.CGImage;
    layer.frame = startFrame;
    return layer;

}
```

In My UIVIewController Class I called my static function as following:

```
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer =  [GradientView greyGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    CALayer *imgLayer =[ItemView imgLayer];
    imgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:imgLayer above:bgLayer];
```

And it works! now I can make drawings on my image.